# Change video property on innerHtml of an IFrame

Tags: jquery, html, video, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have this `iframe` for my embed youtube video:

```
<iframe class="event-video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/myvideoid?showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=myvideoid&controls=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3"></iframe>
```

I use `loop=1` to loop the video, but everytime it restarts it loads again (the video freezes for a few seconds with the "loading" gif of youtube).

Since I want my video to loop continuously (seamless), this solution does not please me.

I discovered that if I right click on the video it shows me a HTML5 video box with some options, one of them to "loop" the video. If I click on this option, it changes the `video` element on the innerHtml of the `iframe` adding `loop` property to it.

[image]

And it solves my problem. The video doesn't reload on every loop anymore. My question is: how can I do this with jQuery? Is there some safe way to add this `loop` property on `video` element of `iframe`'s innerHtml?

Comment: The SOP prevents you from reaching into the iframe in any way. I'd suggest you rather look into the JS-based player and its API - see if that can render the `video` element directly into the main document's DOM, so that you can manipulate it directly as well.

Comment: Another idea is to skip YouTube all together and use a standard HTML5 video. Obviously this means bandwidth costs and longer load times, but it would give you full control of the video. You could use a CDN to avoid those issues, but yeah, that's expensive. Just a thought, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to change that because the video is not played on the same domain that your code is, which mean you cannot access the elements inside that iframe, however you can use youtube's JS API in order to loop your video when it ends.

This code will not add the "loop" attribute to the `<video>` element inside the iframe, but it will give you the loop feature that you are looking for (without reloading the video, just play it from the beginning):

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test</title>
            <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'M4Xrh8OP1Jk',
                    events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                console.log(event.data)
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                }
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but unfortunately it "blinks" when the video is "restarted". Its not 100% seamless, perhaps 99%, but that 1% still bothers me. But as my question was about be or not be possible (to modify the iframe content), I will accept this answer.